# Data retrieved from Firebase not run into View

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve data from my realtime database and bring it to the Card view. After some debugging, I know that I already got my data to the rowitems arrayList but somehow it not running into the View method.

My code:

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
//        isFinished = true;
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if(currentUser==null){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, IntroductionMain.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
        else{

            String CurrentUID = currentUser.getUid();
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(CurrentUID).child("Online").setValue("true");
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(CurrentUID).child("Seen").setValue("online");
            swipeCard();

        }
    }
```

swipecard (this is where I get data from Firebase)

```
  private void swipeCard(){
        currentUserId = currentUser.getUid();
        setupTopNavigationView();
        userArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        rowItems = new ArrayList<>();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");

         ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        if(!snapshot.getKey().equals(currentUserId)) {
                            User user = new User();
                            user.setUser_id(snapshot.getKey());
                            user.setName(snapshot.child("Name").getValue().toString());
                            user.setAge(snapshot.child("Age").getValue(Integer.class));
                            user.setImage1(snapshot.child("Image1").getValue().toString());
                            user.setImage2(snapshot.child("Image2").getValue().toString());
                            user.setImage3(snapshot.child("Image3").getValue().toString());
                            user.setStatus(snapshot.child("Status").getValue().toString());
                            user.setJob(snapshot.child("Job").getValue().toString());
                            user.setSchool(snapshot.child("School").getValue().toString());
                            user.setSex(snapshot.child("sex").getValue().toString());
                            user.setCompany(snapshot.child("Company").getValue().toString());
                            user.setFishing(Boolean.parseBoolean(snapshot.child("Fishing").getValue().toString()));
                            user.setMovie(Boolean.parseBoolean(snapshot.child("Movie").getValue().toString()));
                            user.setMusic(Boolean.parseBoolean(snapshot.child("Music").getValue().toString()));
                            user.setSports(Boolean.parseBoolean(snapshot.child("Sports").getValue().toString()));
                            user.setGaming(Boolean.parseBoolean(snapshot.child("Gaming").getValue().toString()));
                            user.setTravel(Boolean.parseBoolean(snapshot.child("Travel").getValue().toString()));
                            userArrayList.add(user);
                        }
                        else{
                            sex = snapshot.child("sex").getValue().toString();
                        }

                    }
                    getCards();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        };
        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(eventListener);

    }
```

getCards to put which data i need to Card object.

```
private void getCards(){
        for(User user: userArrayList){
            if(!user.getSex().equals(sex)) {
                Cards cards = new Cards(user.getUser_id(),
                        user.getName(),
                        user.getAge(),
                        user.getImage1(),
                        user.getStatus(),
                        user.getCompany(),
                        user.getSchool(),
                        user.getJob(),
                        user.isMovie(),
                        user.isFishing(),
                        user.isTravel(),
                        user.isSports(),
                        user.isMusic());
                rowItems.add(cards);
            }
        }
        arrayAdapter = new PhotoAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.item, rowItems);
        checkRowItem();
        updateSwipeCard();

    }
```

and the adapter of to view Card

```
public class PhotoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Cards> {
    Context mContext;


    public PhotoAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<Cards> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final Cards card_item = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        }

        TextView name = convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        ImageView image = convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        ImageButton btnInfo = convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkInfoBeforeMatched);

        name.setText(card_item.getName() + ", " + card_item.getAge());
        btnInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ProfileCheckinMain.class);
                intent.putExtra("name", card_item.getName() + ", " + card_item.getAge());
                intent.putExtra("photo", card_item.getProfileImageUrl());
                intent.putExtra("bio", card_item.getBio());
                intent.putExtra("interest", card_item.getInterest());
                intent.putExtra("distance", card_item.getDistance());
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        name.setText(card_item.getName() + ", " + card_item.getAge());

        switch (card_item.getProfileImageUrl()) {
            case "defaultFemale":
                Glide.with(getContext()).load(R.drawable.default_woman).into(image);
                break;
            case "defaultMale":
                Glide.with(getContext()).load(R.drawable.default_man).into(image);
                break;
            default:
                Glide.with(getContext()).load(card_item.getProfileImageUrl()).into(image);
                break;
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Ok I retrieve all data from Firebase and store it to userArrayList so that I can filter it later, because Realtime database doesn't have option to select with multiple conditions. After filtering userArrayList, I bring all data  needed to Cards and show them to the users. The problem is there's no Cards showing. I think because it takes time to get data from Firebase, it never got over the swipeCard function?

Comment: Ah finally fix it. Just put arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() and it works.